# How to execute the javascript in tabpanel item in ExtJS4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm building a website that use ExtJS, once I click a button
it calls Ajax to load a html page, and add it to tabpanel as an item.

```
mainTab.add({
    xtype: 'panel',
    html: ajaxResponse.responseText
})
```

But the javascript in that html page does not execute , 
how to solve this problem? Thanks very much!

**EDIT**
It seems I have found it out， any better solution is welcome:

```
 mainTab.add({
    html:'<iframe src="'+UrlText+'" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>'  
 })
```

Comment: why not using `ComponentLoader` it easier for me. `ComponentLoader` also load the page via ajax, and support for script option. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentLoader-cfg-scripts

Comment: How to use it ? I can not find any good example

Comment: sure. see my answer. hope you get it.

Answer (score 2):

You can add iframe using http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ux.IFrame

here is example

```
mainTab.add(Ext.create('Ext.ux.IFrame',{
  src:'http://www.google.com',
  title:'google'
}))
```

Comment: Hi, how can I fire the load event on Ext.ux.IFrame?

Answer (score 2):

```
myCompLoaderPanel = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel",{
    width:200,
    height:300,
    title:"From ComponentLoader",
    loader:{
        autoLoad:true,
        scripts:true,
        url:"a.html"
    }
});

mainTab.add(myCompLoaderPanel);
```

for me, this is the easier way..
cause i do not need to handle manually the ajax call. just put it in url config.

and this is how to load the loader :  `myCompLoaderPanel.getLoader().load()`
this is usefull if you set `autoLoad: false` for the loader.

Comment: This works fine with only load one a.html, but when load a.html multiple times ( mainTab.add multiple times) , the javascript in a.html did not execute! why?